# Approximating $L^1$ function with convolutions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

> Let $f\in L^1([0,1])$, and suppose that $\int_0^1f\varphi^{(n)} = 0$ for every $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(0,1)$, where $\varphi^{(n)}$ is the nth derivative.  Show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$
>   (Given hint: Approximate $f$ by smooth functions using convolutions)

Thoughts:
Going off the hint, we choose $\psi\in C_c^\infty$ such that $\int_0^1\psi =1$ and define $\psi_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\psi(x/\epsilon)$ so that $(f*\psi_\epsilon)\to f$ in $L^1$

After this, I'm a bit unsure.
If we somehow show $\int_{[0,1]} (f*\psi_\epsilon)^{(n)}\varphi = 0$ (which I haven't), and letting $\epsilon \to 0$, how would that show $f$ is even differentiable, and a polynomial.

Comment: The product rule of convolutions says it doesn't matter which function takes the derivative. That is, $(f * g)' = f' * g = f * g'$. I'm sure we can do the same for distributions and use the hypothesis.

Comment: that is a very cool rule

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to move the convolution from $f$ to $\varphi$. Just to have the definition well posed we assume $f,\ \varphi$ and $\psi$ to be defined as $0$ outside $[0,1]$ (convolution is defined on the whole space).
$$\int_0^1 (f*\psi_\epsilon)^{(n)}(x)\varphi(x)dx=(-1)^{n}\int_0^1 (f*\psi_\epsilon)(x)\varphi^{(n)}(x)dx=\\
(-1)^{n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(y)\psi_\varepsilon(x-y)\varphi^{(n)}(x)dydx=\\
(-1)^{n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(y)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi_\varepsilon(x-y)\varphi^{(n)}(x)dxdy=(-1)^{n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(y)(\tilde{\psi}_{\varepsilon}*\varphi^{(n)})(y)dy=\\
(-1)^{n}\int_{0}^{1}f(y)(\tilde{\psi}_{\varepsilon}*\varphi^{(n)})(y)dy=
(-1)^{n}\int_{0}^{1}f(y)(\tilde{\psi}_{\varepsilon}*\varphi)^{(n)}(y)dy=0,
$$
where $\tilde{\psi}(t):=\psi(-t)$. Just to elaborate a little bit:

- The second equality holds because the support of $\varphi^{(n)}$ is contained in $(0,1)$.
- The third equality from the bottom holds for $\varepsilon$ small enough because the support of
  $\tilde{\psi}_{\varepsilon}*\varphi^{(n)}$ is contained in an $\varepsilon-$neighborhood of the support of $\varphi^{(n)}$ which is a compact contained in $(0,1)$.
- The second equality from the bottom is just one of the properties of the convolution.
- The last equality comes from the assumption because 
  $(\tilde{\psi}_{\varepsilon}*\varphi)^{(n)}\in C_c^\infty(0,1)$ (again for $\varepsilon$ small enough)